# Unique identifier across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Unique identifier across multiple tables?

Using MySQL, I'm trying to associate products with a purchase order.
Those products can become from different tables probably with different schema's.
I cant associate because of the identity of each product by schema, not by all kinds of products.

Cellphone

```
+-----+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------+
| id  | brand  | version | color | capacity | price |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------+
| 1   | iphone | 5s      | black | 16       | 9500  |
| 2   | iphone | 5s      | white | 32       | 10000 |
| 3   | iphone | 5s      | blue  | 32       | 10000 |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------+
```

Course

```
+-----+-----------+------------+-------+
| id  | topic     | idschedule | price |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------+
| 1   | Photoshop |  1         | 9500  |
| 2   | HTML5     |  2         | 10000 |
| 3   | CSS3      |  3         | 10000 |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------+
```

I've made a table Product, that together with a product identity, produce an unique identifier.

Product

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | Schema    |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | Cellphone |
| 2   | Course    |
+-----+-----------+
```

ProductEspecification

```
+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+
| id  | idproduct | idespecification | quantity | idpurchase |
+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+
| 1   | 1         |  1               | 10       | 1          |=> 10 iphones
| 2   | 2         |  3               | 1        | 1          |=> 1 CSS3 course
+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Stackoverflow search "database subtypes".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use abstraction and [Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).

An abstract thing you sell (good, service, etc) is called a Product.

An abstract physical good you sell is called a Good. Good inherits Product.

An abstract service you offer is called a Service. Service inherits Product.

Cellphone inherits Good.

Course inherits Service.